# "The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'?

Tags: spring

My xml schema is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">
```

and my spring jar files are of `3.2 version`.
Why does it give the following error:
 `"The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven' "`?

Comment: Please check your error statement There is something at the last after element.Statement was like "The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element XYX".What is XYZ in your case? check it and update the question so that you can find solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing mvc and context entriy in your **xsi:schemaLocation** attribute.

Change your  `xsi:schemaLocation` like this

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd"
```

Comment: thank u, this problem is solved but another problem is occured

Comment: @iftekhar Your welcome.If answer helps you make habit to accept the answer.Yaa what is the other problem ?

Comment: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation. DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping]

Comment: @iftekhar Collect all jars as per your requirement and add that in your project.